# Align NSToolbarItem according to NSSplitView in fullscreen mode

Tags: swift, macos, split, fullscreen, nstoolbar

I need to align a NSToolbarItem according to my SplitView. I was looking for something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372245/align-nstoolbaritems-with-nssplitview-columns/41372712), but I do not think it is a good idea to use apple's private method. Then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32564698/8395981), that did the trick.

This is what I have now:

```
func addToolbarConstraints() {
    if let toolbarItems = delegate.baseWindowController.window?.toolbar?.items {
        if let n = toolbarItems.index(where: { $0.label == "EditPreview"}) {

            toolbarItems[n].view!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            toolbarItems[n].minSize = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 0.0)
            toolbarItems[n].maxSize = CGSize(width: 1000.0, height: 100.0)
            toolbarItems[n].view!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        }
    }
}
```

Now to the real issue. Unfortunately this will stop working when user enters fullscreen mode. The reason for that is the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'**

Indeed, if we check the View UI Hierarchy through debugger, we can note how the NSToolbar will no longer be under the main "NSWindow - Window" view hierarchy. Instead, there will be a separate item called NSToolbarFullScreenWindow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA65L.png

I believe this is the root cause... Any idea to make this works also when users goes into fullscreen mode?